# UIScrollView got freeze when Back button pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am having a (`UIView` and `UICollectionView` in a `UIScrollView`) as `1stVC`. I have to scroll both at the same time for which I already unable the collection view scrolling. So first time When I launch that screen I am able to scroll the whole view, But when I push to (next `ViewController`) `2ndVC` and then press Back Button to `1stVC` my scroll view is not preforming it got Freeze.

Tried this Method:-

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

        for(UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
            contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,view.frame);

        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
    });
}
```

Tried this Method:-

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];

}
```

And For Getting Dynamic Height of the Collection view I have Done This

```
CGFloat height = _collectionCompass.contentSize.height;
```

Which I Have provided to ScollView ContentSize.

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, height);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you manually set collectionView size? Constraints or UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol. Depending on your use case. It's hard to tell without the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

What I really suggest it's to remove scroll view and do all stuff in collection view, since with scroll view you're missing some of benefits (e.g. cells reusing). Also collection view in scroll view it's a bad practice.
From [Apple style guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/scroll-views/):

> Don’t place a scroll view inside of another scroll view. Doing so creates an unpredictable interface that’s difficult to control.

If your UI as list, you can add view as header of collection view or as another cell. With this approach you can remove the code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`